# Angular 6 - getting issue in reactive forms when working with lazy loading module

Tags: angular

I am trying to create an application which has two feature modules (lazy loading), public and admin. In the public module I am creating a login form. In the App Module I have imported ReactiveFormsModule. Below is the login.component.ts file code

```
import { AppService } from './../../app.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private service: AppService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      'email': new FormControl(null),
      'password': new FormControl(null)
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.loginForm);
  }

}
```

and corresponding html file code is

```
<section>
  <form class="form-signin" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">   
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" formControlName="email" required autofocus email>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" required>    
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
  </form>
</section>
```

Below is AppModule.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I am doing this I am getting this below error in the browser console panel

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("<section>
  <form class="form-signin" [ERROR ->][formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">   
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please"): ng:///PublicRoutingModule/LoginComponent.html@1:28
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("<section>
  <form class="form-signin" [ERROR ->][formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">   
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please"): ng:///PublicRoutingModule/LoginComponent.html@1:28
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module should import `FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule`.

Comment: Yes. I did in the AppModule.

Comment: Actually this was working fine in Angular 5. When I started to build a new app with Angular 6, this issues has been raised in console.

Comment: Can you share your AppModule?

Comment: Yes I did. Please check.

Comment: You have not imported the `CommonModule` ??

Comment: Cannot reproduce what you got. Have a look here: https://sg-reactive-form-jcxtps.stackblitz.io

Comment: `CommonModule` is there in the PublicModule (feature module). Ok. Now, what I have done is. I have moved login code in the app component and this is working fine. but somehow this is not working in feature module. I am loading this feature module with lazy loading.

Comment: Oh. You have to import these formsmodule and reactiveformsmodule in your feature module tooto make it work

Comment: @chetan You should import `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `PublicRoutingModule` since your `LoginComponent` resides there

Comment: @yurzui. Its working perfectly now. Thank you so much for sharing this solution.

Answer (score 1):

import `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` in `appmodule.ts` file.

```
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: Please add some more details, like how it will fix the problem?

Comment: If you are loading a feature module as lazy loading in main module and feature module has a login component then we need to import the Forms/ReactiveForms Module in the feature routing module to make it work login form. I hope this will help.